# Glitches in CSS when hovering over different divs and parts of the browser

Tags: html, css, onhover, tilt

Link to my codepen: `[Codepen]`(https://codepen.io/sunylkwc-the-selector/pen/xxBPRGx?editors=1100)

When you hover different parts of the webpage the weird glitches occur on the transparent cards, such as when you hover the third card glitches appear on the first card as a faded line and when you hover the read more button of the second card same thing happens.

[image: hovering back and forth over button inside second card produces vertical glitch line in the first card]

I tried switching my browser but it was still there.

Comment: Just a note : it doesn't happen on FF 122.0, it does happen on Chrome 121.0.6167.86.

Comment: @puzzler Thank you for the note, I'll try opening it on FF also, but still I want it to look seamless on chrome too.

Comment: When I removed this line: <img class="img" src="d5745a76-49a1-46ab-90bd-29cb85fc04b2.jpg" alt=""> the glitching stopped.

Comment: FYI StackOverflow supports runnable code snippets as well. Use the `<>` button to make your code run directly within StackOverflow. It always helps if the code you're asking about is in the question.

Comment: Cannot repro on latest Chrome on M1-mac build `121.0.6167.85`

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question; please do not just send us to external platforms to see relevant code.

Comment: Also can't reproduce; neither in Chrome nor Firefox (current versions, Mac OS Ventura)

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for your inconvenience, i wansn't aware that people might suffer reproducing the problem also i didn't knew that there is also a runnable code snippet feature just cuz i am a newbie here, I'll take care of it from now on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested in Edge v120.0.2210.144

The issue stems from your `backdrop-filter: blur(0px);`, `transform` and `box-shadow` on the card elements.

The tilt-glare effect you are using is affecting the shadows and the backdrop filter.

There are a couple of fixes you can employ, though the main way is a bit of effort.

1. Remove either the backdrop filter or the box-shadow
2. Reduce the shadow size significantly to `5px 5px 5px`
3. Split the shadow into its own pseudo-element so that the filters can't interact with it

The simplest and best-looking fix is to drop the shadows or the blur, from my experimenting with your codepen.

The effects can be used together in current browser versions but not quite with the way you have built the page.

Essentially what you are seeing is a flicker in the blurred area of the shadow emphasised by the effects on the other cards (I believe)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I removed the drop shadow it finally fixed the flickering and made it seamless :))